# Grouping data with condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

i want to grouping the data but there have a rules

ex my df is

```
df <- data.frame(NAME = c("ALEX", "ALEX", "ALEX", "BRODI", "BRODI", "BRODI"),
                 CLASS = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 TIME = c(1213, 1314, 1415, 1213, 1415, 1617),
                 SALARY = c(100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300))
```

the time is starttime to endtime and with char type data
i want to group by name,class and time to summarize the salary but the time will be group if there are equal start and end time (ex 1213,1314,1415) will be 1 group to (1215) and salary will be summarize and (1213,1415,1617) can't be group because the time isn't continue.
my expected df is

```
df2 <- data.frame(NAME = c("ALEX", "BRODI", "BRODI", "BRODI"),
                 CLASS = c("A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 TIME = c(1215, 1213, 1415, 1617),
                 SALARY = c(600, 100, 200, 300))
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar. Show your efforts. Define what “start time” and “end time” are and why `diff.time` cannot be used?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated and there are likely more elegant approaches, but one approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr` would be to (1) grouping by `NAME` and `CLASS` only, first determine consecutive times from row to row by first separating out the start and end times, then (3) calculating the difference in the end in one row and start from another (`diff`). It should be zero if consecutive, so `cumsum` will create a new "group" for each non-consecutive time. Then (4) you can create the new time using the start time from the first consecutive row and last time from the last consecutive row, and finally (5) `summarize` based on the new data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(TIME, sep = 2, into = c("start", "end"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(end) - as.numeric(lead(start)),
         diff = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(diff), lag(diff), diff)),
         time2 = paste0(substr(TIME[1],1,2), substr(TIME[n()], 3, 4)),
         TIME = case_when(diff == 0 ~ time2, TRUE ~ as.character(TIME)),
         .by = c(NAME, CLASS)) %>%
  summarise(SALARY = sum(SALARY), .by = c(NAME, CLASS, TIME))
```

Output:

```
   NAME CLASS TIME SALARY
1  ALEX     A 1215    600
2 BRODI     B 1213    100
3 BRODI     B 1415    200
4 BRODI     B 1617    300
```

Note that `tidy::separate` in this case is now superseded by `separate_wider_position`, so could switch out the `separate(...)` line with `separate_wider_position(TIME, c(start = 2, end = 2), cols_remove = FALSE)` for good practices (but I find the latter less intuitive).

I would suggest you run this line-by-line to see what's going on. Good luck!